# Application should enter background while click on a button

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad

How to make the app to enter background when a button clicked inside an App in iOS ?

Comment: Press the Home button.

Comment: You can't do this from within the App, there are no interfaces which would allow to do this from within the app and Even you do it, I'm pretty sure apple would object to it

Comment: Why would you want to do that?

Answer (score 0):

Regarding the apple policies, if you are going to submit your application to the app store, it wont be allowed to be published. It´s a principle of user experience and an application which allows to close the app by itself,tries to send the app to the background etc,. is not allowed regarding the apple policies and development guidelines. Your application will be rejected straightaway with a message like that. Anyway, the only logic to send your app to the background in my opinion would be to share some information between applications as you can do sharing information as it was introduced in iOS 3.0 if my mind doesnt act up, so you can open another application and load this data (it replicates the data in the target sandbox of the other application but never shares the same information like other applications do ). You can find this example (not this specific one, just a closer one) in Safari, when you want to download something and it says "open with the app X" and its copied to the sandbox if the format is allowed for this application. In the other hand, you can share some documents between your family of applications, so can open a document in your other application if it´s installed. There are 2 logical cases of why an app would have to be sent to the background. But in my opinion, there are not so many situations in that you would like to send an application to the background unless you want to do something odd like having a keyboard observer to track the information the user is writing in the background, but anyway it would be rejected and the app lifecycle doesnt allow that. When your application goes to the background, which is not closed state, you are not allowed to do a lot of things for obviously, security reasons.